# Algorithm negotiation fail Jsch with OpenSSH

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, openssh

Can someone tell me how server or client part can be configured to have common cipher?

It throws `com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail`

Server side uses OpenSSH and the log shows:

`no matching cipher found: client aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc server aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com`

JSCH version used is 0.1.43, I have tried to run it with java 8 and have updated JCE jars(as suggested in other similar posts) but without success

Comment: what is the set of server-side acceptable ciphers? see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25662/openssh-default-preferred-ciphers-hash-etc-for-ssh2 for reference to where the configs might be

Comment: Use more recent version. There is [0.1.54](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) out there which supports reasonable cipher suites.